# How can i sort the categories by ID

Tags: posts, categories

Hi all I am newbie to wordpress
I am using the wp_list_categories in the sidebar to display the categories .
How can i display thus categories sort by id 
any one much appreciated...

```
<?php wp_list_categories('exclude=73');?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_list_categories` takes an `orderby` parameter which accepts :

- ID - Default
- name
- slug
- count
- term_group

So the default behavior of  wp-list-categories is to order by ID but you can specify that like so:

```
<?php wp_list_categories(array('exclude'=> 73,'orderby' => 'ID'));?>
```

Comment: I get this error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '(' in /home/content/67/7399467/html/banas/wp-content/themes/Banas/sidebar.php on line 6

Comment: <?php wp_list_categories(array('exclude'=> 73,'orderby' => 'ID'));?>           and it's working thanks Much appreciated

Comment: opps, fixed it.

Comment: Many thanks ,Without your help i did'nt solve that problem ...